# How to get radio button value inside a label?

Tags: html, radio-button, label

newbie here, I was wondering why is it that I am unable to get the value of radio button inside a label?

```js
function myButtonTrigger(c) {
  if (c.value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("id1").style.display = "table-row";
    document.getElementById("id2").style.display = "none";
  } else if (c.value == "2") {
    document.getElementById("id1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("id2").style.display = "table-row";
  } else {}
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #39739D;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
This is my Button

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="choices" onClick="myButtonTrigger(this)"></input>Dental
           </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
           <input value="2" type="radio" name="choices" onClick="myButtonTrigger(this)"></input>Rehab
             </label> </div>

This is the data to be hidden.<br><br>

<table>
  <tr id="id1">
    <td id="id1">Dental Data</td>
    <td id="id1">Specialization Data1</td>
    <td id="id1">Schedule Data</td>
    <td id="id1">Room Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id2">
    <td id="id2">Rehab Data</td>
    <td id="id2">Specialization Data2</td>
    <td id="id2">Schedule Data</td>
    <td id="id2">Room Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/biyasuzimo/1/edit?html,js,console,output — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. An `id` must be **unique**.

Comment: @Quentin do we have a way to get the value of a radio button inside a label?

Comment: As I said, I couldn't reproduce the problem. So yes, you do already.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded the whole code, please see below.

Answer (score -1):

Just use .checked property

```
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("choices");

function myButtonTrigger() {
  if(radioButtons[0].checked) {
    // first radio button checked
  } else if(radioButtons[1].checked) {
    // second radio button checked
  }
}
```

Or you can use query selector to get element by value:

```
if(document.querySelector("input[name='choices'][value='1']").checked)
```

EDIT: don't use the same id on two or more elements, you can use it only on  tag and it will work. ID means identity, unique. Some good alternatives:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2, #id3, #id10000, #anotherId");
document.querySelectorAll("table tr#id1 td"); // marks every td in tr with id id1 in table (really, tr and td in table, wow)
```